# Android: getting back after playing video

Tags: android, video, orientation

I am working on an application where the user have a video list with play buttons on each row of listview. Whenever the user plays the play button, a separate activity is started for playing video. The problem I am having is that I have to press the back-button twice in order to return to the main Video. Moreover, I have set my video to landscape mode. When my original application is in portrait mode and the video is in landscape mode and then I return to my main application, it crashes. however, when my application or my device is in landscape mode and I play a video, then it is fine when I go back. So, I have two questions

1- Why I have to press the back button twice to go back to the mainActivity (I have also used onBackPressed in the video activity to finish the current activity but its not working)
2- Why my application crashes when it is in the portrait mode and the video plays in the landscape mode and while returning to the main application, it changes the video to portrait mode as well for sometime and then crashes. Here is the code of my video playback (i don't know why I have to press back button twice to go back to the main application)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    filename = extras.getString("videofilename");
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    path=filename;
    if (path == "") {

        Toast.makeText(
                ViewVideo.this, No video found,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

          mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
          mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
          mVideoView.requestFocus();
          mVideoView.start();

    }
}


  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
   {
   Log.v(TAG,"movie finished");
   finish();
  }}
```

I hope my question was clear and someone will be able to help me

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Activity will destroy recreated it self if the orientation changes from portrait to landscape and vice versa,for that reason when you go back from land to port it may be some of the variable which you used in port activities may not be set,possibly throws NullPointerException.It is better if you provide more details like logcat and code.

Comment: Actually the problem is that, I don't encounter these errors while I am running application on the emulator. They only get occur when I use them on a device.. If only one issue can be resolved, it can resolve both issue and that issue is that why I have to press back button two times in order to get back to the original application. I have updated my question to include the code of my videoplayback function.. can you help me here?? thanks

Comment: I thought, android video player is separate Application,when you first time pressed it closes that application,second time it closes the above activity and then it will go to your main activity

Comment: okay.. is there any way to finish the current activity once i press the back button first time.. I really need to finish the whole activity when back is finished (only once, not twice).. any suggestions???

Comment: you can't do more than one activity finishes through onBackPressed() method.it is tricky used lifecycle of activites for this implementation

Comment: Sir!! do you have any idea how to initially hide the control buttons of video (play,pause, rewind, forward) once the video starts.. these controls are shown as soon as the video starts.

Comment: See hide() method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html and use setMediaController(MediaController controller) in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Answer (score 0):

**1.** To avoid double back clicking when playing video you can simply write:

```
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    ((Activity) getContext()).finish();

                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

**2.** To prevent application from crashing when portrait mode changes, add to your AndroidManifest.xml tag *android:configChanges* like that:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

So, your activity won't be recreated.

Comment: just be aware that recreating `Activity` after config change is there by default for a reason - read all about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html